# Remove empty space in string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a string which contains a list of tags. Each tag redirects to another page. For example `PS4, Xbox360, PC` But it also passes the empty space as `%20Xbox360`. How can I remove this %20?

This is how I render tags:

```
@foreach($niz as $n)
   <a href="/search?q={{$n}}" class="tags">{{$n}}{{$loop->last ? '' : ','}}</a>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%20` is just whitespace url-encoded. So, [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) it, then [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) it:

```
<?php
$string = "%20Xbox360";
$string = urldecode($string);
$string = trim($string);
var_dump($string); // Xbox360
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/o4tH7)

And to do this while `echo`ing in Blade, just do it inside the curly braces:

```
<a href="/search?q={{ trim(urldecode($n)) }}" class="tags">{{$n}}{{$loop->last ? '' : ','}}</a>
```

Comment: I've figured it out in the meantime. That's why I've deleted my comment. Thx, I will accept your answer when time elapses!

Comment: Glad I could help. I added it to the answer anyway for completeness' sake.

Comment: It should be in href section though - `<a href="/search?q={{trim(urldecode($n))}}" class="tags">{{$n}}{{$loop->last ? '' : ','}}</a>` .. But thx again

Comment: @harunB10 fixed :)